# Deleting a single row from a table that has multiple entries?

Tags: database, phpmyadmin, rows

So here's my situation.

I have a table in my database, it has multiple entries, but I need only one to be deleted.

When trying to google this, all I could find was questions referring to deleting all except one of these entries, while I need to delete ONLY ONE and leave the rest.

I'm completely confused on this, and don't really understand how to do it.

Comment: If you're using phpmyadmin, can't you check off a row and press delete?

Comment: I do not think that this place is right for this kind of question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a where clause to identify the row that you want to delete, preferably by the primary key of the table.  For example:

```
delete from MyTable where id = 1
```

If you post your table's schema, we can help with better syntax.

Answer (score 1):

The row you are trying to delete should have a unique way to identify it, typically the primary key. You would then use the `WHERE` clause to specify your query to `DELETE` it:

```
DELETE FROM sparkles WHERE primaryKey = 1
```

Alternatively, if there are no keys, you would filter by criteria that matches all values of the record you wish to delete.

```
DELETE FROM sparkles WHERE col1 = 5 AND col2 = 15 AND col3 = 51
```

Comment: Alright, do you know a way to insert ids into every row, but add one each time, so that row 1 is id 1, and row 2 is id 2?
I have a lot of rows in this table.

Comment: thank you. This helped me, I've added the AUTO_INCREMENT column, and now it's working :D

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to achieve this in Java, you would most probably be using JDBC however if this is just a onetime effort you can directly run the delete query with appropriate where clause.

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't see how this is tagged as Java. But it sounds like you want to use limit operator, like this:

```
DELETE FROM somedatabase WHERE someentry = 5 LIMIT 1;
```

The response two above me is good to but leaves out LIMIT.

Answer (score 0):

Step by step for doing it in phpMyAdmin....

1. Go to phpMyAdmin interface
2. Select the database
3. Select the table
4. Click Browse
5. Look for the row you are looking to delete and click the delete Icon
6. Confirm deletion of that row

Done.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 5 Fields in table and you want to delete only one field for particular instance then you should fire update query giving the null effect to that filed...

Suppose If table is
Id | Name | MobNum

And you want to delete MobNum of record 5 ...then query can be ike this>>>

update tlbName set MobNum=null where Id='5'